# Is it true that $\int _0 ^1 f(x) dx > 0$ if and only if there exists an uncountable collection of irrational real numbers?

Tags: integration, general-topology

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be Riemann integrable. Is it true that $\int _0 ^1 f(x) dx > 0$ if and only if there exists an uncountable collection of irrational real numbers $y \in (0, 1)$, such that $f(y) > 0$?

Comment: No, that's wrong. A function is Riemann integrable on a finite interval iff it is bounded and continuous almost everwhere (with respect to the Lebesgue measure). The indicator function of the Cantor set $C$, i.e. $\chi_C(x)=1$ for $x\in C$, $\chi_C(x)=0$ for $x\notin C$, satisfies the conditions, because it's continuous in the complement of $C$ having full measure. The Cantor set is uncountable, still the integral is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E\subset [0,1]$ be the set of points of continuity of $f$.
Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, the Lebesgue measure of $[0,1]\setminus E$ is $0$.
If $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in E$, then $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 0$, hence there exists a point $x_0\in E$ such that $f(x_0) > 0$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exists an interval $I\subset [0,1]$ of positive length containing $x_0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for every $x\in I$.
But such an interval contains an uncountable collection of irrational real numbers.

Comment: That's the "only if" part. You can't prove the "if" part, because that's wrong.

Comment: That's correct. I have proved that, if $\int f > 0$, then there exists such a set of points.